# Which algorithm is this?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am studying for the exams and I am looking at my notes, where I came across with an algorithm, but there is no title, so I don't know which algorithm it is and it doesn't also exist in my textbook. It handles graphs. I will post it here, maybe someone knows which it is.
$$Input: G=(V,E),a\epsilon V$$
$$\text{For each v} \epsilon V :$$
$$μ_{v}=a$$
$$l_{v}=0 \text{(length of path})$$
$$A:=\varnothing \text{(the vertices,that I have checked)}$$
$$B:=\{a\} \text{(the vertices,that I check)}$$
$$C:=\varnothing \text{(the vertices,that I will check at the next "level")}$$
$$i:=0$$
$$\text{While } B\neq \varnothing :$$
$$i=i+1$$
$$A:=AUB$$
$$\text{For each } v \epsilon B \{ $$
$$\text{For each } u \epsilon \text{ adjacent(v)\A} \{ $$
$$μ_{u}:=μ_{v,u}$$
$$l_{u}:=i$$
$$C:=CU\{u\}$$
$$A:=AU\{u\} $$
$$\} \} $$
$$B:=C$$
$$C:=\varnothing$$

Comment: Well, do you know what the algorithm does for a graph? (e.g. shortest path, minimum spanning tree, etc?)

Comment: It appears that $\mu$ and $l$ are properties of each vertex.  What do these designate?

Answer (score 4):

What you have there is a **breadth-first traversal** of the graph, with a few extra bells and whistles to construct a *breadth-first spanning tree* along the way and remember which level of the spanning tree each node ends up in.

Answer (score 2):

Except for the $\mu_v$, this seems to traverse a graph, starting from a (given) node $a\in V$. For all nodes in $v\in V$, it sets $l_v$ to the length of the shortest path connecting $a$ and $v$. If the graph is not connected, not all nodes will be evaluated. I don't know what $\mu_v=\mu_{v,u}$ does.